# Can't find C: and D: disks in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I removed windows 10 and installed ubuntu 16.04.01. While installing I chose 2nd option (can't remember exact name but description was like erases all programs of all operating systems). Now I can't see contents of my C: and D. Can you help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have mistakenly erased your entire disk and did a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 install, you should have paid a close attention to that option before doing, as Android Dev said that's exactly what the situation is.

Answer (score 4):

## Your files are now history

The option you selected doesn't just erase the programs and operating system, it formats the entire drive, and wipes out the partition table and MFT.

You can try to recover you partitions with `TestDisk` as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu), but no guarantees.